# Paypal DirectPayment returning error

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

while using PayPal sandbox `DirectPayment` method I am getting the following error message:

```
Direct credit card payment API call failed: Please enter a valid postal code in the billing address.Short Error Message: Invalid DataError Code: 10712
```

I have changed my Zipcode and address but no use. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please any one help me on this

Answer (score 0):

This error is often caused by the zip code not matching the city and state format. I would suggest using usps.com zip code verfication to make sure the zip matches the postal service city and state. You can find this tool here:

https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupAction!input.action

Using this tool usually helps me clear the error. If this doenst help resolve the issue, please show the address and zip details that you are currently sending. Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Comment: I have used below address as my billing address.
1 Main St,
San Jose,
CA-95131
United States

Comment: I just tested dodirectpayment in sandbox with this address and it worked. Can you please share all of the information that you are submitting?